# same Virtualized Development Environment, different client sites

Tags: vmware, virtualization

I spend a lot of time working at multiple client sites, and want to keep my development environment as consistent as possible.  I was considering using a single virtual machine image which contains my development environment, which ideally can be run at any location. What are expected performance bottlenecks to face and how do you handle them? 
I don't know the fastest way to run this setup, but I currently have a USB 3.0 external hard drive.  Would disk I/O be a bottleneck, and what are the alternatives? e.g. [SSD](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_85_0?rh=n:172282,n%3a!493964,n:541966,n:193870011,n:1292116011,k%3assd,p_85:2470955011&bbn=1292116011&keywords=ssd&ie=UTF8&qid=1359273700&rnid=2470954011)? 
Should the same copy of the virtual machine work on machines of different instruction set architectures (e.g. AMD, Intel, ARM)?

I am only using VMWare Player at the moment. I code in high-level languages.

Answer (score 1):

We use VMware fusion, with ssd drives. You need to work out how much ram and processing power the vm needs, and ensure the host has enough to run itself and the vm.

You also have trouble if u always need to leave and rejoin windows domains. It might be easier to buy a high spec laptop, and run ur vm. Keep a copy of ur vm on another disk encase something happens.

Comment: Right now not all places I work allow devices like laptops. With VMWare fusion, have you had any issues running the same VMWare machine on different hardware (e.g. Intel and AMD)?

Comment: The files are usually 30 gig or more, it will take some time to copy them across drives. Also, if the client doesn't like external devices, they are probably not going to like you running your own OS on their network.